# Calling WCF from asp.net web application makes web ui hangs til wcf connection closed

Tags: asp.net, wcf, client

The Problem is when i am calling wcf webservice from asp.net Web Application UI hangs til webservice finishes it processing and connection to service get closed. 
The problems comes in very badly when i am calling webservice using AJAX, Complete UI Hangs till service connection get close.
If you could give me any clue?

Comment: Does the service returns something?

Comment: Yes service is answering properly, but during that time while service is executing no database and other operations can be performed

Comment: If the service is really performs time consuming operation then I would call the service asynchronously and there by ASP.NET threads don't get blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The UI thread is on hold until the service call completes.

You need to call the service asynchronously - or if it's likely that the client will have 'moved on' from the page before the service call completes, make the WCF call [One Way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) - in this case the service response happens instantly, the UI thread continues and the WCF service processes the request on it's own thread. Obviously there is no completion response from a one way call.